# Is there a way to see if there is already a banner in view with ionic content banner?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, banner

I have an issue in my app where if there are 2 errors happening at the same time then I get 2 banners overlapping each other and I can't see the error messages. Is there a way to check if there is already an open banner? Angular 1.5.3 and https://github.com/djett41/ionic-content-banner

```
var showContentBanner = function (type, data) {
   $ionicContentBanner.show({
                            text: data,
                            type: type,
                            interval: 3000,
                            transition: 'vertical'
                        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to; before opening a banner; closing it :

```
//define a global variable 
var contentBannerInstance;

//CLOSE content banner if it exists!!!
      if (contentBannerInstance) {
        contentBannerInstance();
        contentBannerInstance = null;
      }

//open the banner 
 contentBannerInstance = $ionicContentBanner.show({ ...})
```

Comment: Does this apply to a situation where my content banner is inside a service rather than a controller? If it's inside a service how can I close it when the route changes?

Comment: sure; with that solution; you affect the event of $ionicContentBanner to a globalVariable (that is on the head of your service/controller) and you "purge" before creating a new one